# detect multitouch while pressed c#

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I want to detect a touch event and do something while my finger is touching down.

What is the event I need?

I tried Manipulation*, Pointer*, Touch*, Stylus*, Holding*, etc...

If you have a sample code, better.

The most accurate code I have is this. But only works with finger moving.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Name="Rect1" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="108,50,309,169" ManipulationDelta="Rect1_ManipulationDelta"  />
    <Rectangle Name="Rect2" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="338,50,79,169"  ManipulationDelta="Rect2_ManipulationDelta" />
    <TextBox Name="Text1" Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="108,267,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <TextBox Name="Text2" Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="338,267,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{

public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    System.Windows.Input.ManipulationModes currentMode = System.Windows.Input.ManipulationModes.All;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Rect1_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable = 0;

        variable = Convert.ToInt32(Text1.Text);
        variable++;
        Text1.Text = variable.ToString();
    }

    private void Rect1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable = 0;

        variable = Convert.ToInt32(Text1.Text);
        variable++;
        Text1.Text = variable.ToString();
    }

    private void Rect2_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable = 0;

        variable = Convert.ToInt32(Text2.Text);
        variable++;
        Text2.Text = variable.ToString();
    }

    private void Rect2_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        int variable = 0;

        variable = Convert.ToInt32(Text2.Text);
        variable++;
        Text2.Text = variable.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Touch* events will give you just touch.  Pointer* will give you touch and mouse and stylus.

Use *Down to know when a touch goes down and *Up to know when it goes up.  If you want to do something repeatedly while the touch is down, create a DispatcherTimer on the *Down and stop it on the *Up

Comment: Hello again, I customize the application to work with DispatcherTimer, I think is not the best option, but works.

Comment: I designed Microsoft's touch APIs.  This is the right approach

Comment: When I click for example a TextBox, and gets focus, the UIElement with the dispatchertimer, doesn't work with fluency... Any help?

Comment: you'll need to describe your problem in more detail

Answer (score 0):

UIElement/ContentElement.TouchDown is the event you need to accomplish what you are after.

Example:

```
<Rectangle Name="Rect1" IsManipulationEnabled="True" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Margin="108,50,309,169" TouchDown="Rect1_TouchDown" />

private void Rect1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

For further information, refer to: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.touchdown(v=vs.110).aspx and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This doesn't works, the TouchDown only did 1 execution.